# How to show negative numbers in a financial table for accessibility

Tags: html, financial, accessible

I am coding these tables in HTML and am required to code for accessibility.  Financial tables typically show negative numbers in parentheses.  Is that considered 508/WCAG compliant?  Or should negative numbers be shown as -$100.00?

The title of the table is "Tax Revenue in Millions of Dollars"  and the table headings are years, and then percent change.  The table itself doesn't mention dollars.  Do I need to put dollar signs before the numbers?

Comment: How is this a coding question?

Comment: This might not be the right spot to post this I'd try here: http://quant.stackexchange.com/

Comment: It is a coding question because I am trying to code these tables accessibly in HTML. It's not a question about how to represent the numbers - I already know how they do it in print.

Answer (score -1):

[Oracle Help](https://mybi.omb.in.gov/analytics/olh/l_en/appaccess003.htm) implies that parentheses are accessible enough. I would add the dollar signs, but it's a matter of knowing your users. For instance, would you also need to specify that they are US dollars?